# Como criar uma Anonymous Thread em Delphi

Tags: delphi, thread

Gostaria de saber como criar uma Anonymous Thread em Delphi, se puder mostrar um exemplo ficarei grato.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Anonymous Thread em Delphi** são muito usadas para executar processamentos paralelos.

Um bom motivo para usarmos **Thread** é quando precisamos executar um ou vários processos relativamente pesados, porem não queremos que nossa aplicação fique bloqueada devido a execução dos mesmo.

Para criarmos uma Thread devemos invocar o método `CreateAnonymousThread`  o qual cria uma instância derivado de um TThread que simplesmente irá executar um método anônimo do tipo tproc passado como parâmetro na chamda do método.

Quando invocamos o método `CreateAnonymousThread`   a Thread vem com a Property  `FreeOnTerminate` default True, o que faz com que a instancia da Thread seja destruída apos sua execução. Para manter a Thread criado set `FreeOnTerminate = False,` porem você deve destruir a instancia da Thread manualmente invocando o método Terminate; Vale lembrar que uma Thread é criada suspensa, para inicia-la você deve invocando o método `Start()`.

Outra questão que devemos ter cuidado é quando necessitamos atualizar a tela, ou seja, manipular componentes visuais, assim sempre que necessário devemos utilizar o método `synchronize` da Thread  onde os processos executados dentro deste método são direcionados para a Thread principal executar, pois os objetos da **VCL** não podem ser diretamente atualizados em uma Thread que não seja a principal.

Um exemplo:

```
var 
 myThread : TThread;

begin 

  myThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread( procedure begin

     // seu codigo que deseja ser executado dentro da thread


  end);

  myThread.start();

end;
```

Ou também:

```
begin     
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin

     // seu codigo que deseja ser executado dentro da thread


  end).start();

end;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
procedure TForm1.StartThread(const Id, LogId: Integer);
begin
 TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var I: Integer;
    begin
      for I := 0 to 100 do
      begin
        Sleep(Random(100));
        LogMsg(Format('Thread: %d; Logitem %d', [Id, I]), LogId);
      end;
    end
    ).Start;
end;
```

Você pode usar tudo em apenas um conjunto com Start.
Nesse exemplo coloco a variável I dentro do procedure, pois fora dá erro.